# SQLOLEDB/ADODB version 10 takes forever to open a connection

Tags: sql-server, tcp, oledb, ado, adodb

Consider the following VBA code from MS Access:

```vb
Private Declare Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32" () As Long
Sub QuickTest()
    Dim s As Long: s = GetTickCount
    Dim cn As Object
    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=sqloledb;Server=10.54.146.90,14330;" & _
                          "Database=MyDb;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
    cn.Open
    Debug.Print GetTickCount - s; " ms elapsed (Version " & cn.Version & ")"
End Sub
```

I run the above code on two different systems, one with Windows 10 and SQLOLEDB/ADODB version 10:

```vb
 16593  ms elapsed (Version 10.0)
 9500  ms elapsed (Version 10.0)
 9485  ms elapsed (Version 10.0)
 9469  ms elapsed (Version 10.0)
```

And another with Windows 7 and SQLOLEDB/ADODB version 6.1:

```vb
 967 ms elapsed (Version 6.1)
 531 ms elapsed (Version 6.1)
 515 ms elapsed (Version 6.1)
 531 ms elapsed (Version 6.1)
```

Why does **SQLOLEDB/ADODB version 10** take nearly *twenty times longer* to open a connection to the same database as **SQLOLEDB/ADODB version 6.1**?  Is this a bug in the SQLOLEDB/ADODB version, a known issue, or something else?  Can I still use version 6.1 on my Windows 10 machine?

**More info**: I'm simply calling this function from the immediate window in Access.  Both systems are 64-bit Windows.  Both systems are 32-bit MS Access.  The Win 7 machine is using MS Access XP (i.e., 2002).  The Win 10 machine is using MS Access 2013.  Both machines are connected to the same LAN.  The remote SQL Server is being accessed over a VPN.

---

In an effort to achieve an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I also came up with the following VB script.  This is similar to the above code, but runs against a local instance of SQL Server (copy and paste the below code to a file named AdoSpeedTest.vbs):

```vb
s = Timer()
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=sqloledb;Server=.;Database=master;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
cn.Open
et = (Timer() - s) * 1000
WScript.Echo Round(et) & " ms elapsed (Version " & cn.Version & ") "
```

If I run AdoSpeedTest.vbs on my local SQL Server Express instance with TCP/IP disabled, it takes about 4 - 5 seconds on average.  If I enable TCP/IP on my local instances, it takes about 16 - 25 *ms* on average.  The connection is opened correctly in both cases (I verified this with a longer script that retrieved contents of a database table), it just takes a lot longer when TCP/IP is disabled.

I did test the remote connection to SQL Server under both scenarios (local SQL Server TCP/IP enabled and disabled), but that seemed to have no impact on the performance when creating connections on the remote server.

---

<strike>**UPDATE 2**: Upon further investigation using ProcMon, I've found that the remote connections are using two different protocols to connect.  The slow connection is using UDP and the faster connection is using TCP.  Why would one connection use UDP while the other uses TCP when connecting to the same remote server?  Could it be a problem with a local firewall preventing me from using a non-default SQL Server port?</strike>

---

**UPDATE 3:** The remote connections are both using TCP.  The confusion with UDP was likely due to all the noise inherent in using ProcMon.

I tried running WireShark on the database server then connecting to the database from ADO 6.1 and ADO 10.  After spending several hours sifting through that noise, the following critical difference remained:

In the slower version, there were two extra [ACK]-only packets that each generated a 4.5 second delay.

Here's a WireShark screenshot of the fast connection's TCP stream:

[image: fast connection's TCP stream]

And here's a WireShark screenshot of the slow connection's TCP stream:

[image: slow connection's TCP stream]

Note the delay introduced after numbers 355 and 515.

Comment: I cross-posted this question on the [Microsoft support forum](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware/ado-version-100-slow-to-create-connections/8496c6be-4f0c-45a0-bf13-233a549f988a?tm=1441656468435).

Comment: How are you calling the function in MS Access? Behind form, in macro, directly in VBA IDE? Do both systems use same version of MS Access? Are both 32-bit or 64-bit OS machines? Is SQL Server directly connected on same LAN network as both machines or remote (e.g., IP address)? If local, are connections hard-wired or wireless, WLAN? Please provide information in post.